# How to post data having HTML content in query string

Tags: android, http-get

I need to post my string to server having html content,

Here is my code

Url Builder

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .authority(domain)
    .path(pageName)
    .appendQueryParameter("myaction", "dopost")
    .appendQueryParameter("mesg", msg.replace("\n","<br />"));
```

And the generated url looks like

```
domainname/pagename?myaction=dopost&mesg=Hello%2C%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3ETesting
```

execute http code

```
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
getRequest.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, MIME_TEXT_HTML); // html/text, utf-8
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
```

but this will not posted getting forbidden error after executing

Thank in advance

Comment: you are *posting* with a *get*Request?!

Comment: yes I am using get request to post message

Answer (score 0):

maybe a silly mistake, but a post usually is done with an `HttpPost` instead of an `HttpGet`
and looks like this:

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);    
}
```

Comment: for research or for any other reason?

Comment: I am using web api so I must go with this